# xmlhttp.responsetext.split while loops

Tags: php, javascript, while-loop, xmlhttprequest

I have some javascript that pulls some mysql data using xmlhttp.responsetext.  I've been using it to populate form data for a drop down box and it has been working well.  However, I have a need to add a second dropdown menu in the form and it is not working right.

What is happening is both dropdowns are populating with data from 2 different tables when each dropdown should only be getting its data from its respective table.

Could use some help figuring this out, thanks.

Here is the javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1;
     function addInput(div){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
          var newdiv = document.createElement(div);
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<table><tr><td>Line Item " + (++counter) + "</td></tr><tr><td width='190'>Item: <select name='item[]'>" + xmlhttp.responseText.split( "[BRK]" ) + "</select></td><td width='100'>Qty: <input name='quantity[]' type='text' size='2' /></td><td width='500'>Description: <input name='description[]' type='text' size='60' /></td><td width='150'>Amount: <input name='amount[]' type='text' size='6' /></td><td>Tax Rate: <select name='taxrate[]'>" + xmlhttp.responseText.split( "BRK" ) + "</select></td></tr></table><br />";
         }
          document.getElementById(div).appendChild(newdiv);
     }

xmlhttp.open("GET", "dropdownquery.php", false);
xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
```

And here is php.

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/connect.php";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM salesitem");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM salestax");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value=\"".$row['name']."\">".$row['name']."</option>";
}
echo "[BRK]";    

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    echo "<option value=\"".$row2['amount']."\">".$row2['name']."</option>";
}
echo "[BRK]";    

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you split a string, you get an array. I suppose you want to do this:

```
var splitResponse = xmlhttp.responseText.split( "[BRK]" );
var firstDropdownContent = splitResponse[0];
var secondDropdownContent = splitResponse[1];
```

Then use the two new variables to build your HTML.

Comment: Didn't seem to work unless I have it formatted wrong.  Both dropdowns are empty.  I created the 3 variables globals variables.  The inner.HTML was edited as such  <select name='item[]'>" + (firstDropdownContent) + "</select>  both with and without the parenthesis.

Comment: That should be working. Try to `console.log(splitResponse)`, and check your browser console to see if the content is there.

Comment: When I execute the javascript, the following is reported.  ReferenceError: xmlhttp is not defined.  NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER: Component returned failure code 0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER) [nsIDOMHTMLDivElement.appendChild]

Comment: You should use the code I posted right before you assign to `newdiv.innerHTML`. Other than that, your ajax code looks strange (part of it in the addInput function, part outside); but since you state you get some data into the dropdowns with that code, I'll just assume it works, somehow.

Comment: Yep, that did it!  Thank you!  I'm open to modifying my code to make it "less strange" if you are willing.

Comment: @Tom That would probably require a separate question, and more context (like where you call addInput).